# DRY when assigning object properties

Tags: javascript, object

Is there an elegant way to get rid of all the `parsedData.` words? This looks very not-DRY to me..

```
function foo(parsedData) {
  const finalData = {
    KPP: parsedData.KPP,
    OGRN: parsedData.OGRN,
    principalShortName: parsedData.name.short,
    principalFullName: parsedData.name.full,
    principalLegalAddress: parsedData.address.legal,
    principalRealAddress: parsedData.address.real,
    OKATO: parsedData.OKATO,
    principalRegistrationDate: moment(parsedData.history.registration),
    principalTaxRegistrationDate: moment(parsedData.history.taxRegistration),
    OKOPF: parsedData.OKOPF,
    OKVED: parsedData.OKVED,
    headFullName: parsedData.head.fullName,
    headTitle: parsedData.head.fullName,
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes. Use destructuring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try object destructuring. Reference: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring

```
function foo({KPP, OGRN, name, address, OKATO, history, OKOPF, OKVED, head}) {
  const finalData = {
    KPP: KPP,
    OGRN: OGRN,
    principalShortName: name.short,
    principalFullName: name.full,
    principalLegalAddress: address.legal,
    principalRealAddress: address.real,
    OKATO: OKATO,
    principalRegistrationDate: moment(history.registration),
    principalTaxRegistrationDate: moment(history.taxRegistration),
    OKOPF: OKOPF,
    OKVED: OKVED,
    headFullName: head.fullName,
    headTitle: head.fullName,
  });
}
```

It improves even more with shorthand property notation for the properties whose source and target names are the same:

```
function foo({KPP, OGRN, name, address, OKATO, history, OKOPF, OKVED, head}) {
    const finalData = {
        KPP,
        OGRN,
        principalShortName: name.short,
        principalFullName: name.full,
        principalLegalAddress: address.legal,
        principalRealAddress: address.real,
        OKATO,
        principalRegistrationDate: moment(history.registration),
        principalTaxRegistrationDate: moment(history.taxRegistration),
        OKOPF,
        OKVED,
        headFullName: head.fullName,
        headTitle: head.fullName,
    });
}
```

Comment: That certainly helps. For many of those (the ones where the target and source property names are the same) you can take advantage of shorthand property notation as well: `const finalData = { KPP, OGRN, ... };`

Comment: You could move all of the renaming to the parameter list destructuring, but you basically end up with as much repetition as the original. Striking a balance (like the above mostly does) makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
function foo({ KPP, OGRN, OKATO, OKOPF, OKVED, name, address, history, head }) {
  const finalData = {
    KPP, OGRN, OKATO, OKOPF, OKVED,
    principalShortName: name.short,
    principalFullName: name.full,
    principalLegalAddress: address.legal,
    principalRealAddress: address.real,
    principalRegistrationDate: moment(history.registration),
    principalTaxRegistrationDate: moment(history.taxRegistration),
    headFullName: head.fullName,
    headTitle: head.fullName,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is okay to repeat yourself, as it will be less code in this case to do so. I don't think you should do the following just to adhere to the DRY principle, but here we go.

We can utilize object property shorthand in combination with object destructuring to get rid of some of the repetitions.

```
   const { KPP, OGRN, OKATO, OKOPF, OKVED } = parsedData;
   function foo(parsedData) {
      const finalData = {
        KPP,
        OGRN,
        principalShortName: parsedData.name.short,
        principalFullName: parsedData.name.full,
        principalLegalAddress: parsedData.address.legal,
        principalRealAddress: parsedData.address.real,
        OKATO,
        principalRegistrationDate: moment(parsedData.history.registration),
        principalTaxRegistrationDate: moment(parsedData.history.taxRegistration),
        OKOPF,
        OKVEDD,
        headFullName: parsedData.head.fullName,
        headTitle: parsedData.head.fullname
    }
```